# linux-swap partition is in extended drive

Tags: filesystem, partitioning, swap

My apology if my question sounded silly, but I am very new to ubuntu. I have just formatted my pc to ubuntu. However, I found out that now I have 3 partitions in my harddisk. One is the ext4 /dev/sda1 which is the system file partition. However, I noticed that I have another partition called extended /dev/sda2 3.08G, and the linux-swap /dev/sda5 is under the extended partition as shown in gparted. May I know is the ubuntu installed correctly? I can only access to my main system partition, and have lost 6G. My harddisk is 80G and ram 1.5G. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be okay. The swap partition is used as virtual memory to extend your RAM. If you want u can remove it, but if you frequently max out your RAM you might wanna leave it. If you do remove it, its not a bad idea to delete its "mount line" in /etc/fstab (needs root privileges).

Answer (score 1):

If the `swap` partition is in `extended`, then you can't add them (2*3 = 6), but it is together 3G. And that's a reasonable amount, if you have 1.5 G real RAM. Or did I misunderstand? How big is the system partition?

You have to use the same tools, to take the measurements, since 80GB isn't 80GiB - often the numbers are intermixed, and then you get wrong results.